# Load data from Google Datastore to Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-ml

I was trying to run a ML Engine training job reading data from Cloud Datastore, but a got a permission error:

```
line 434, in _end_unary_response_blocking raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline) grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, Missing or insufficient permissions.)> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py",
```

I ran the same script locally and it run well. 
I searched how to add Datastore permission to Cloud ML but didn't find anything...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! Please take the time to go though https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. You should show the code and the full traceback. Is the datastore data in the same GCP project?

Comment: You can either use your credential via gCloud or grant datastore access to Cloud ML Service Account in your project. I recommend you to do the later.

Comment: Thanks you guys. I am using the same project for both services. I was trying to do the second option but didn't find how. Finally I resolved the problem loading another service account with a json file and referencing it inside the python task.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you are using Cloud ML Engine & Cloud Datastore in the same project, or if you have the Cloud Datastore API enabled.  You can probably follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/working-with-cloud-storage#setup-different-project to ensure the service account your Cloud ML Engine workload runs as is able to access Cloud Datastore.